# How to scrape dynamically rendered data from a webpage with Selenium and Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am currently facing some difficulties scraping a website that is using react to render parts of its website and I'm not exactly sure why I can't scrape the data.

Here is the html of the website:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7ktF.png)

What I would like to do is to grab the text of the button with `data-test="shipItButton"`

However when I run my code, I get this error:

```
(node:23294) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[data-test=shipItButton]"}
```

Here is my current code:

```
const webdriver = require("selenium-webdriver");
const By = webdriver.By;
const until = webdriver.until;

const driver = new webdriver.Builder()
  .forBrowser("chrome")
  .build();

let getData = async(url) => {
  await driver.get(url);
  let element = await driver.findElement(By.css('[data-test=shipItButton]'));
  await driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(element), 15000)
    .then(element => getText())
    .then(text => console.log("What is text: ", text))
    .catch(err => console.log("Failed to get: ", err));
}
getData("https://www.target.com/p/animal-crossing-new-horizons-8211-nintendo-switch/-/A-76780148")
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Fix this area.

```
By.css("button[data-test='shipItButton']")
```

Comment: I just tried this and I still get the same error:   ```UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[data-test='shipItButton']"}```

Comment: Sorry forgot the button tag.

Comment: What do you mean by the button tag?